# Using [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]] to let the scheduled selectors fire

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsrunloop, performselector

In my application at some point I have a bunch of messages scheduled using `performSelector`.

Under some conditions, while handling an UI action, I need to wait for all the currently scheduled selectors to fire.

I could place my code in another method and schedule it using `performSelector:target:argument:order:modes:` with `order` value high enough to be sure it will fire last, but there are reasons why I think that would make an ugly solution.

So I send `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]]` and it seems to work just like I need it to.

Still, I'm not sure if that is a legitimate way to let the run loop roll for just one iteration. Also, are there any potential troubles associated with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question.

First of all it's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723608/nsrunloops-and-forcing-event-processing) (also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923621/is-calling-nsrunloop-rununtildate-a-good-idea)).

Next, generally, sending `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]]` from within the same run loop is a bad idea:

1. In theory, autorelease pool will get drained that way. In practice, I've not been able to make my app crash by using objects allocated pre-`runUntilDate` (under ARC), but better not to risk anyway.
2. If somehow another action gets dequeued during that `runUntilDate` it might cause some unexpected side effects.

TL;DR I should do myself a favor and replace that piece of code with something more deterministic.