# Why is my UIProgressBar not being updated?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is how I am attempting to update my UIProgressView in my iOS app.

```
[self.progressView setProgress:3.0/10.0 animated:YES];

// check the value.
NSLog(@"Progress: %0.1f", self.progressView.progress);
```

Why is NSLog outputting 0.0? Shouldn't it output 0.3? The progress bar isn't changing either.

Comment: What happens if you use animated:NO and %g instead of that single precision float?

Comment: Are you sure that `self.progressView` is not `nil`?

Comment: Are you updating the progress bar on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you set the progress value on the main thread. (and that `self.progressView` does in fact refer to your `UIProgressView`)

If that doesn't help, you may want to explicitly give the runloop some time to catch up on UI changes, e.g. using:

```
NSDate* futureDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0.001 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:futureDate];
```

However, you should be very careful using hacks like this, see:

- [Is calling -[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:] a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923621/is-calling-nsrunloop-rununtildate-a-good-idea)
- [Using [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]] to let the scheduled selectors fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371971/using-nsrunloop-currentrunloop-rununtildatensdate-date-to-let-the-schedul)
- [NSRunloops and forcing event processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723608/nsrunloops-and-forcing-event-processing)